# ASP.NET MVC Access appSettings value in view and maintain its state

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I have added reCAPTCHA to a test website and I would like to access the public key in the view by passing it from the web.config file, through the controller and into the view. I have successfully done this with ViewBag, ViewData, and TempData.

My problem is that this method only works once. In other words, if the validation fails for any reason, then the reCAPTCHA disappears from the site. Is it possible to pass this value and maintain the state, as opposed to hard coding the public key on the view (and having to remember to change it manually upon deployment)?

Note: there is code code that is commented out for testing purposes to demonstrate the implementation of either method.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    // TempData["recaptchaPublicKey"] = AppSettings.recaptchaPublicKey;
    ViewBag.recaptchaPublicKey = AppSettings.recaptchaPublicKey;
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
// @{ var recaptchaPublicKey = TempData["recaptchaPublicKey"]; }
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    // <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@recaptchaPublicKey"></div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="ViewBag.recaptchaPublicKey"></div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning it to `TempData`? What is wrong with `data-sitekey="ViewBag.recaptchaPublicKey"`? (its not really clear what your issue is). If validation fails in the POST method and you return the view, you just reassign the `ViewBag` property as you did in the GET method

Comment: I have modified my post to be a bit more clear - sorry about that. But, as you mentioned, I was missing code to reset the value in the HttpPost method. So, I now have code in both the public ActionResult Register() and in the public async Task Register() Thank you.